# I have an ERC-20 token created. How does it get value now?

Tags: tokens, ether, etherscan, economics

Ok, so a friend of mine helped me create an Ethereum token for me with a 1M supply. I call it the POTTA token. I have also started distributing my token to other friends with a tool that he built so I sent some POTTA tokens to a few friends. As of right now, everything is obviously valued at $0. I just wanted to know how do I add value to my token. So for example if I want each token to be worth say $0.0001 how do I do it?

This is the token contract:

https://etherscan.io/token/0xd521849Fee7901f483Ac06c065225D2497aC0184

Comment: I don't even know of a single one to do it. Maybe you could help me figure it out rather than closing?

Comment: Well, for starters you can ask your friends to send you something in return instead of giving it away for free.

Comment: I can do that but how will they pay me for the token? It needs to go on an exchange for me to do that right? And no, that link still doesn't answer my question. So, for example, I have a friend who is willing to pay $0.01 for 100 tokens, how do I make the transfer so it adds value to the token and not having him paypal me the money?

Comment: Add in your contract something like `function buy() external payable {mint(msg.sender, someFunctionOf(msg.value));}`.

Comment: But I don't have the code for the smart contract. Can I not do it without the solidity code? I just have the 1M tokens at my disposal.

Comment: OK, then as for `how will they pay me for the token?` - you should first define how you **want** them to pay you for the token!

Comment: And that goes in Solidity code too? Say if I have ether and I want them to pay me in ether, what do I do?

Comment: Give them the address of your account and ask them to transfer ether to it.

Comment: So if they transfer Ether to that account, I will have Ether in my account but how will my POTTA tokens get value?

Comment: Buy promising your friends that you will give them ether back if they transfer your tokens back to you.

Comment: There are people who don't mind spending a few cents on this to own that token so I don't need to do back and forth, I just want to create value for that token. You solution is still not clear. Also, do you now realize that this may actually have been a valid question and can you considering re-opening it?

Comment: No, it's not valid under the rules of this site, and you're the one who should be realizing this from our conversation above. There are way too many specific details missing here. You should do some preliminary work of studying the Ethereum eco-system and concepts, then learn a bit of the major languages and frameworks in use (e.g., Solidity, Truffle, Web3, etc). Then, if you have a technical issue that you're unable to solve - you can post it here while including all the relevant technical details (your code, settings, configuration, etc). Your question as it stands is just way too general!

Comment: Ok, is there any place I can get help for my question that you are aware of? I still don't understand how to achieve what I was looking for, to get value for my token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108136/discussion-between-p0tta-and-goodvibration).